# Sthala Purana of the Thiruneermalai Temple

Tags: vishnu, history, temple, sri-vaishnava

In the Divya Desam called Thiruneermalai, Lord Vishnu resides in four different forms:

a) Sri Neervanna Perumal (literally meaning, Lord with the complexion of water) 
b) Sri Ranganatha 
c) Sri Narasimha 
d) Sri Trivikrama

[image: Neervannar]

[image: Ranganatha]

[image: Narasimhar]

[image: Trivikramar]

This temple is praised in 19 Pasurams  by Thirumangai Azhvar, and in 1 Pasuram by Bhoodhatthazhvar, in the Nalayira Divya Prabandham.

For those who don’t know, the Nalayira Divya Prabandham is a collection of 4,000 verses by all the 12 Azhvars. It is held in high respect by the SriVaishnava Tradition, to which I belong.

Now, the Pasurams state that when Thirumangai Azhvar went to Thiruneermalai to worship the Lord, the whole hill on which the temple is situated was full of water, and he had to wait for six months to worship the Lord again.

But, my question is: what is the Sthala Purana of this temple, and why did the Lord appear at this place?

Comment: it is not advisable for us to post pictures of garba-graha perumal (even though they are already available online, no need to repost it and widen the audience)